# Why is the answer to the query on [1]?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay first off, here's my function for sending a query:

```
function send_query($sql) {
global $rows;
global $conn;
connect();

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $rows[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();

return $rows;
}
```

And when I use it like this:

```
$rows = send_query("SELECT views FROM posts WHERE postid = " . $_GET['id']);


foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        print_r($row);
        echo "<BR>";
    }
```

I get this result...

```
Array ( [postid] => 1 [username] => jesusfreak [unique] => 3 )
Array ( [views] => 0 )
```

Why is it putting the answer I need in [1] of the array instead of [0]? And why is it putting those other things that I didn't request into [0]?

Comment: Don't EVER EVER EVER insert a $_GET value inside your query. If you can't solve this issue, go for a foreach track instead of a 'for ($i; ...) ....'  style. Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why should you never insert a $_GET value inside a query? Is it just for security concerns?

Comment: It opens you up to SQL injection.  User input should always be sanitized

Comment: [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), that's why... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: It's not a small matter: SQL injection doesn't need much knowledge or skill to be done => a lot of people with bad intentions can use it => protect yourself against it.

Comment: Great point. I'll do that! I'm still not understanding why it's putting the information on [1] instead of [0] though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is because your

```
global $rows
```

is coming in with a result already inside it.  You are appending the newly queries rows to that variable.

Try using a different (empty) array instead of $rows:

```
function send_query($sql) {
global $rows;
global $conn;
connect();

$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sqlresults = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $sqlresults[] = $row;
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
$conn->close();

return $sqlresults;
}
```

Comment: The $rows array is empty. It declares it empty at the top of each page.

Comment: I don't think it is empty, otherwise you would not have the [0] result with fields you aren't querying for: Array ( [postid] => 1 [username] => jesusfreak [unique] => 3 ).  Globals will be passed into your send_query function since you declared it, prepending them to the resultset. You have to be careful with Globals.  Humor me and try my code suggestion

Comment: How about just not defining `$rows` as global since the function returns it anyway?  Get rid of the global!

Comment: @AbraCadaver Correct, it would not need to be defined at all.  I was taking into account if this was pseudo-code where it could be used elsewhere and leaving it, but appending the results to a new array :)

Comment: Excellent! The problem was that I forgot to unset it before redeclaring it. Well done! :)

Comment: Strange though. When I change the "global $rows" to $rows = array(); in the function it stops working.

Comment: Are you changing the return back to $rows from $sqlresults as well? I changed that in several places.